# Logistic map and attractors

Tags: soft-question, chaos-theory, complex-systems

Does the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) have a [strange attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor) for some "chaotic" values of the parameter?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78441/16660

Comment: @Wouter I don't understand the answer given there. Can you summerize it? Does such attractor exsist?

Comment: Have you taken the time to absorb what Manishearth wrote? All but the last paragraph seem fairly straightforward to me... What part is getting the better of you?

Comment: The short answer according to what @Manishearth wrote is that the logistic map *does* have an attractor, in fact a whole series of them. However, I'm not sure if those attractors have a fractal structure, which would make them strange attractors... Perhaps he can expand on that.